# Apple TV recognized over Wi-Fi but not Ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, appletv

My setup is as follows:

- A modem
- High speed wireless router (Belkin)
- Apple TV

The modem feeds the router and the router is connected to the Apple TV. Now when I connect the Apple TV to the router via Wi-Fi everything is good and all my Apple devices recognize the presence of the Apple TV. The strange thing is if I connect the Apple TV to the router via an Ethernet cable (my thinking being to reduce the load on the router, and get smoother AirPlay), none of the devices connected to the same router recognize that the Apple TV is live.

My iPhone, iPad, and MacBook are all connected to the Belkin router via Wi-Fi.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem streaming from my iPad to Apple TV via a Linksys WAG160Nv2 router.  Worked fine when the Apple TV was connected to the router by WiFi, but not at all when connected by Ethernet.

The problem was resolved by disabling Internet Access Priority (aka QOS) on the router.

Before I tried this, I got some slight improvements in behaviour by disabling SPI Firewall Protection and the option to Block Anonymous Internet Requests, but neither of these tweaks were required once I disabled QOS.

It does seem odd that these apparently WAN-related options affect the internal bridging between Ethernet and WiFi, but that's what seems to be happening.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your WLAN and LAN networks are separate from each other, you'll need to change your Belkin settings to make sure devices on one network can see devices on the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the IGMP setting in your router. This is a common occurance on Verizon FIOS networks, but not necessarily restricted to them.